# What names are used for certified "mechanics"?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, pilot-certification

While watching a documentary on the the UK Red Arrow aerobatic team, mechanics were sometimes called *"tradesmen"*, *"technician"*, or *"engineer"*.

In the US they are commonly called *"aircraft mechanics"* or an *"A&P"*.

**What other designations are used for certified aircraft "mechanics"?**

[image]

[image source](https://www.workingmother.com/momlife/13708544/how-much-does-an-aircraft-mechanic-make/)

Comment: Not sure if you realize or not, but you don't have to be certified to work on an aircraft, so "technician" could be relatively accurate, as well as "tradesmen". I'm not sure "engineer" would be accurate though. The requirement (at least in the US) is that anybody can work on an aircraft but it must be done under the supervision of a certified A&P for the work performed, and the A&P is the only one who can sign off. Rules are a little different for home built aircraft though.

Comment: I am a Pilot & A&P :)

Comment: The British seem to use the word "engineer" in many places that we Americans would use the word "mechanic". Not wrong by any means, just different ("lift" == "elevator", "lorry" == "truck", etc)

Comment: What names?  I've worked with Robert, Amanda, Matt, Michelle, Felipe, Leon....  The names are very multi-cultural and varied!  All joking aside, good question.  :)

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Maintenance_Engineer)

> An Aircraft Maintenance Engineer (**AME**), also Licensed Aircraft Maintenance Engineer (**LAME** or L-AME), is a licensed person who carries out and certifies aircraft maintenance. The license is widespread internationally and is recognised by the International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO).

Comment: Which LAME pissed of the guy making those titles?

Comment: Make sure you hire the right type of AME. You can't have the same AME issue your medical and do your annual inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in the British Commonwealth it's Aircraft Maintenance Engineer.  In Canada an AME can do maintenance up to and including an annual condition inspection or other major inspections, but has to be specifically endorsed on more complex aircraft to sign off any kind of work.

In the US the main classification is Airframe and Power Plant Mechanic (A&P), who can do and sign maintenance releases on any aircraft without an endorsement.  However to sign off an annual condition inspection or other major inspections, the mech needs an IA, or Inspection Authorization.

Comment: to make matters more confusing, AME can also mean Aero Medical Examiner, used by EASA and FAA both.

Comment: 14 CFR Part 65 Subpart D refers to it as a mechanic certificate.  Airframe and Powerplant are two separate ratings applicable to the mechanic certificate.  There are also Repairman certificates under Subpart E which are for workers at manufacturers and repair stations.

Comment: The Repairman cert is also for unlicensed people to work on homebuilts if I recall.  Used to be only the original builder got one but now any owner can get one if they take a course.  The rules in Canada for maintaining homebuilts are actually a bit more liberal; whoever's name is on the C of R can sign any maintenance release on a homebuilt, including annuals.

Comment: In the US, an A&P can sign off on a condition inspection (experimental and Light Sport) as well as 100 hour inspections. An IA (A&P with Inspection Authorization) is required to sign off on annual inspections on certificated aircraft.